# C language multiprocessing execvp()

Tags: c, multiprocessing

I have to write a code for following option "--command".

the execvp() fails when I run:

./program --command 1 2 3 cat test.txt

--command i o e cmd args
Execute a command with standard input i, standard output o and standard error e; these values should correspond to earlier file or pipe options. The executable for the command is cmd and it has zero or more arguments args. None of the cmd and args operands begin with the two characters "--".

The part of code that must do execvp() is as follow:

```
      if(optarg){
int fd;
int i = 0;
char *arg[20];
int index;
for(index = optind-1; index < argc && *argv[index] != '-'; index++, i++){
  switch(i){
  case 0:
    fd = atoi(argv[index]);
    break;
  case 1:
    fd = atoi(argv[index]);
    break;
  case 2:
    fd = atoi(argv[index]);
    break;
  default:
    arg[i - 3] = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(arg[i - 3], argv[index]);
  }
}
int j;
for(j = 0; j < i - 3; j++)
  printf("%s\t", arg[j]);
printf("\n\n");
execvp(*arg, arg);
  }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't mention what the nature of the failure is, which makes it hard to help you. The use of `1 2 3` for in, out and err is very weird (stdin is fd 0, not 1) but since you don't seem to actuallybdi anything with tjod arguments, I don't suppose it is related. Copying strings rather than just providing the correct offset into the args array is inefficient and overcomplicated but iy eould work if you correctly null-terminate the array. If you insist on copying the strings, use strlen to figure out the needed size (or just call strdup rather than malloc+strcpy).

Comment: Thank you very much I use strdup() now. The issue is array size. since in my test I only pass two argumeny cat test.txt so the char **arg must have only two strings whereas I declared 20 (char *arg[20]). How can I dynamically add to the size of the char **arg. I don't know how many arguments will pass so I took a bog number but execvp() failed due to having garbage in my big size array.

Comment: Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — it needn't be much larger than what you show, but it does need to reproduce your problem and we need to be able to compile and run it (and see the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I wrote and is using a lot, that may be of help; written in C++ and the target OS is Linux; you can check and adapt the code for C:

```
#define MAX_PARMS 100 //crazy
#define MAX_PARM_SIZE 5120 //make it 5K ///max is command-line-max (4096) i think too lazy to check
#define SPACE_CHAR 32
bool is_valid_space(const std::string s, int pos)
{
    if (s[pos]!=SPACE_CHAR) return false;
    if (!pos) return true;
    if (s[pos-1]=='\\') return false;
    return true;
}
void RunApp(const std::string sApp, const std::string sParm)
{
    if (!isextant(sApp)) return;
    int n=0,i=0;
    while (i < (int)sParm.length()) { if (is_valid_space(sParm, i)) n++; i++; }
    if ((n>=(MAX_PARMS-1)) || ((sApp.length() + sParm.length() + 1) > MAX_PARM_SIZE)) return;
    pid_t pID = fork();
    if (pID == 0)
    { //child..
        if (sParm.length()!=0)
        {
            static char *arsz[MAX_PARMS]; //pointers to offsets in sz[]-buffer
            static char sz[MAX_PARM_SIZE];
            int p=1,t=0,i=0,n;
            n = sApp.length(); //copy app into sz[] as first parm
            while (i<n) { sz[i]=sApp.at(i); i++; }
            sz[i] = 0;
            t = i+1;
            arsz[0] = sz;
            n = sParm.length();
            i=0;
            while (i<n)
            {
                if (is_valid_space(sParm, i)) i++;
                if ((i<n) && (!is_valid_space(sParm, i)))
                {
                    arsz[p] = sz+t; p++;
                    while ((i<n) && (!is_valid_space(sParm, i)))
                    {
                        sz[t]=sParm.at(i);
                        t++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    sz[t]=0; t++;
                }
            }
            sz[t]=0; //double null at end
            execvp(sApp.c_str(), arsz);
        } //NB: here-be-zombies: must waitpid in caller
        else execlp(sApp.c_str(), sApp.c_str(), (char*)0);
        exit(0); //only if exec..-error
    }
}
```